# My program keeps closing after I select Y to continue

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I'm trying to make a program to play Tic Tac Toe. I have it start asking if you would like to play, but when I press Y my program doesn't start running and just closes. I'm not to sure what is causing this. Here is my code :

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

char square[10] = { '0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'};
void showWelcomeMenu();
void showMenu();
int winner();
void board();
int startGame();
int quitApp();

int startGame()
{
int player = 1, i, choice;
char mark;

do
{
    board();
    player = (player % 2) ? 1 : 2;

    cout << "Player " << player << ", enter space number: ";
    cin >> choice;

    mark = (player == 1) ? 'X' : 'O';

    if (choice == 1 && square[1] == '1')
        square[1] = mark;
    else if (choice == 2 && square[2] == '2')
        square[2] = mark;
    else if (choice == 3 && square[3] == '3')
        square[3] = mark;
    else if (choice == 4 && square[4] == '4')
        square[4] = mark;
    else if (choice == 5 && square[5] == '5')
        square[5] = mark;
    else if (choice == 6 && square[6] == '6')
        square[6] = mark;
    else if (choice == 7 && square[7] == '7')
        square[7] = mark;
    else if (choice == 8 && square[8] == '8')
        square[8] = mark;
    else if (choice == 9 && square[9] == '9')
        square[9] = mark;
    else
    {
        cout << " Invalid move ";

        player--;
        cin.ignore();
        cin.get();
    }

    i = winner();
    player++;

} while (i == -1);

board();

if (i == 1)
    cout << "==>\aPlayer " << --player << " wins! ";
else
    cout << "==>\aDraw";

cin.ignore();
cin.get();
return 0;
}

void showWelcomeMenu()
{
char answer;
bool quit = false;

cout << "Welcome to Tic Tac Toe!\n" << endl << endl;
cout << "Would you like to play? (Y/N)" << endl << endl;
cin >> answer;
if (answer == 'Y')
{
    startGame();
}
else if (answer != 'Y')
{
    exit(0);
}



}

int winner()
{
if (square[1] == square[2] && square[2] == square[3])
    return 1;
else if (square[4] == square[5] && square[5] == square[6])
    return 1;
else if (square[7] == square[8] && square[8] == square[9])
    return 1;


else if (square[1] == square[4] && square[4] == square[7])
    return 1;
else if (square[2] == square[5] && square[5] == square[8])
    return 1;
else if (square[3] == square[6] && square[6] == square[9])
    return 1;


else if (square[3] == square[5] && square[5] == square[7])
    return 1;
else if (square[1] != '1' && square[2] != '2' && square[3] != '3' && square[4] != '4'
    && square[5] != '5' && square[6] != '6' && square[7] != '7' && square[8] != '8'
    && square[9] != '9')

    return 0;
else
    return  -1;
}

int quitApp()
{
exit(0);
}

void board()
{
system("cls");
cout << "\n";
cout << "Tic Tac Toe";
cout << "\n";

cout << "Player 1 (X) : Player 2 (0)" << endl << endl;
cout << "\n";

cout << "     |     |     " << endl;
cout << "  " << square[1] << "  |  " << square[2] << "  |  " << square[3] << endl;

cout << "_____|_____|_____" << endl;
cout << "     |     |     " << endl;

cout << "  " << square[4] << "  |  " << square[5] << "  |  " << square[6] << endl;

cout << "_____|_____|_____" << endl;
cout << "     |     |     " << endl;

cout << "  " << square[7] << "  |  " << square[8] << "  |  " << square[9] << endl;

cout << "     |     |     " << endl << endl;
}

int main()
{
showWelcomeMenu();
quitApp();
}
```

Any help would be appreciated! Thank you. Sorry if this has been answered! I couldn't find it.

Comment: And when you used your debugger to run your program one line at a time, and inspect the values of all variables after each line executes, what observations did you make? Have you debugged your program using your debugger, already? If not, why not?

Comment: Most likely, your `cin << answer` reads a character left from your previous input.

Answer (score 0):

The code is working perfectly for me.
Please recheck it.

Maybe you are providing wrong input. like using **y** instead of **Y** (case sensitive)

To ensure that code works despite of case you can modify condition as

```
if (answer == 'Y' || answer == 'y')
{
    startGame();
}
```

---

moreover , I'll suggest you to simplify conditions from that do while loop.
eg.

```
if (choice == 1 && square[1] == '1')
      square[1] = mark;
```

should be replace by

```
if (choice == 1)
      square[1] = mark;
```

same for other conditions that decide which cell to mark.
why? because `choice` is an integer checking it against charecter is not necessary(actually can cause bugs due to implicit type casting)